Center image for mobiles / css
I'm trying to center image for mobiles cause on desktop it seems good but I'm stack.
The link is the following https://www.amongroup.gr/contact/ which is included the photo (header). It has been created with elementor
I've tried most of css but nothing happens.

Please add meaningful code and a problem description here. Don't just link to the site that needs fixing — otherwise, this question will lose any value to future visitors once the problem is solved or if the site you're linking to is inaccessible. Posting a Minimal, Reproducible example (or MCVE) that demonstrates your problem would help you get better answers. For more info, see Something on my web site doesn't work. Can I just paste a link to it? Thanks!

flex justify-content:flex-center to the parent and child div respectively
